# Icefaces 3 ace:ajax event not working

Tags: ajax, icefaces-3

I have some simple code

```
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{data.check}" style="border:0;"  valueChangeListener="#{myBean.actionCheckItem}" 
    partialSubmit="true" >
    <f:attribute name="dataIdx" value="#{data.rowIdx}"/>
    <ace:ajax execute="@this" render="@this" event="valueChange" onComplete="alert('dont');" onStart="alert('start');" />
</ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Ajax work fine, but event onStart and onComplete not working, i'm missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h:selectBooleanCheckbox will working with ace/f:ajax, ice only have partialSubmit="true"